# Analyzing simple two alternative forced choice data

Tags: statistical-significance, randomness

This is probably a silly question, but I haven't taken statistics in a while and am lost. For a class project, I recently performed a really simple 2AFC experiment with 10 subjects. Each subject completed 80 trials and answered either correctly or incorrectly for each trial, so for each subject I have a rate of correct responses.

I'm basically looking to show whether or not the group responses are correct significantly above chance, but don't know where to start. Given what I currently remember about statistics, I was considering just performing a t-test to compare my results with chance results, but don't know if that would be at all appropriate for this situation. Could anyone give me a basic idea to start with?